# document.readyState "Access not allowed" with Applescript +Javascript that waits for page to load

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I'm trying to write an applescript that opens a html page in my browser, waits for it to load, then runs window.find to check for a specific keyword. 
It is very important that the .find can run as soon as the page is loaded but doesn't try before.
If the keyword is present, the script clicks the "next" button.
This is a loop i tried to make, to check whether the html is loaded

```
to checkInteractive()       

    repeat 60 times

        try     
            tell application "Safari"
                set a to do JavaScript 
                "document.readyState" in document 1
            end tell
        end try

        if a = "interactive" then
            exit repeat
        end if

        delay 0.01

    end repeat

end checkInteractive
```

but i get this error:

SYNTAX ERROR Can’t get "document.readyState" in document 1. Access not allowed.

Does anyone know what i should do different? 
Or whether there is another way to check if the html is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put the statement in one line

```
tell application "Safari"
     set a to do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1
end tell
```

or use the AppleScript line separator

```
tell application "Safari"
    set a to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.readyState" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know a line change could affect it in that way. 

Now i changed the line: "if a = "interactive"" to "if a is equal to "interactive"" 
but for some reason the loop does not run on the first page when i call the method but then runs indefinitely on the following pages even though the html is loaded.
Do you have any idea what else could be wrong with it?

Comment: `=` and `is Equal to` are synonyms. Try to check for `complete` rather than `interactive`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Just figured that one out myself too :) Thanks a lot!